# How do I update WPS Office to the latest version in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: updates, wps-office

I want to update WPS Office to the latest version (if possible through command-line), without reinstalling it. I am currently using:

[image: wps-office details]

I checked [here](https://help.wps.com/articles/check-update-office-version-windows) the way to check for updates, but I can't see the *Check for Updates* option.

Am I using the latest version of `wps-office`? If not, then how do I update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a package in snap (what you installed WPS with), you can run the command:

```
sudo snap refresh wps-office
```

To update a package in APT, you can run this command:

```
sudo apt --only-upgrade install package_name
```

Where `package_name` is the package that you want to update.

There you have it!

Answer (score 0):

After pulling the package, go to the directory of the downloaded package and through the terminal run:

```
sudo apt install ./package_name.deb
```